# Parsing "RE" and "FWD" in email subject lines

Tags: email, regular-expressions

I'd like a sanity check on a regex modification I made.  The below code parses out leading "Re:" and "Fwd": in an email subject line and captures the remainder of the subject line.  It works, but throws away any leading "re" even if it's part of a word (e.g. repetition becomes petition).

```
   Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile('^\\s*(?:(?:(?:[Rr][Ee].?)|(?:[Ff][Ww][Dd]?.?)):?\\s*)*(.*)').matcher(subject);
   if (matcher.find()) {
      return matcher.group(1).trim();
   }
```

The modified regex tests OK at:  http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html but I'm wondering what additional test cases people have seen email programs use which this breaks?

```
^\s*(?:(?:(?:[Rr][Ee][^a-zA-Z])|(?:[Ff][Ww][Dd]?.?)):?\s*)*(.*)
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your regex using G Skinner's [RegExrv2.0](http://www.regexr.com/). I think you need to be creating capturing groups for RE, FWD and FW followed by a colon as in RE: FWD: and FW:. That's why your code is interrupting words like REPEAT.

Normally any kind of subject line will have a colon after the RE: or FW:. If it doesn't, it will at least have a blank space, so that would be the alternative way of finding those. Your use of the '.' that follows your letters selects everything that follows the match with the exception of a line break.

Your use of question marks with colons may be part of the cause of the issue you're having. They break up capture groups, allowing you to combine multiple tokens together without creating a capture group. As such, you may have too many of them which could cause your tokens comprising the RE and FWD, etc to **not** to be interpreted as a group; consequently breaking apart words that you don't want broken.

I recommend you visit the link I've provided and try some different combinations until you can produce the results you desire. Note that replace values are entered separately and there's a YouTube video tutorial on how to use the utility. You'll of course want to avoid relying on the the ignore case flag since it can't be used with SF Apex which I can see you're clearly aware of.